# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clearRequests')

Tags: magento2, schedule

**Error**: The infinite loader showing on the page.

When I schedule new update page, block, product,category the infinite loader is show.

> the console display the error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'clearRequests')
> [image]

> file name: insert-listing.js